# Key Vault recovery disallowed by built-in policy

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-policy

**The issue**: Unable to recover deleted key vault.

**Policy assigned**: "Key vaults should have purge protection enabled"

**Policy definition ID**: "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/0b60c0b2-2dc2-4e1c-b5c9-abbed971de53"

**Policy effect**: "Deny"

Even though "enableSoftDelete" is set to true before deletion, in the deleted list, the property is no longer present. When trying to recover the Vault, the policy gets triggered and it does not pass the check for the existence of the "enableSoftDelete" property thus not allowing the recovery as long as the policy effect is set to Deny.

I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong.

**Key Vault properties before deletion**
[image: Key Vault properties before deletion]

**Key Vault properties after deletion**
[image: Key Vault properties after deletion]

**Policy If statement block**
[image: Policy If statement block]

Comment: What is the actual response when you try to recover the vault?  I am no Policy expert, but the condition is is enableSoftDelete == false, not if it does not exist. 

Why are there multiples of the same condition in the if/anyOf block?

I feel like there's more to this than we're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a **delay** after changing the settings in Azure portal. It's better for you to **check if soft-delete is enabled** in Azure Key Vault before deleting, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-change#audit-your-key-vaults-to-check-if-soft-delete-is-enabled).

[image]

If the soft-delete is really enabled, you could try to [delete](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_key_delete) and [recover](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_key_recover) key using Azure CLI.

**NOTE:** You must add Access policies with delete and recover permission, if not, it will return access denied.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Pamela, apologies for the delay. This unfortunately has nothing to do with auditing the soft delete property. I have 2 policies in place to make sure that users are unable to create a keyvault if they do not have softdelete and purgeprotection enabled.
The underlying issue is that after deleting a keyvault with both softdelete and purgeprotection enabled, the "enableSoftDelete" parameter vanishes and thus, the "enablePurgeProtection" policy is preventing the recovery of the vault. 
The policy is set to Deny, not audit. Changing it to audit "resolves" the issue but that is not a solution.